# How to use direct ByteBuffer

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I need to pass a data buffer from `C` to `Java` over JNI. So have created a direct `ByteBuffer` in `C` and sent it to `Java`:

```
void *myBuffer = ...;
int w = ..., h = ...;

jmethodID func = ...;
jobject directBuffer = jni_env->NewDirectByteBuffer(myBuffer, w * h);
jni_env->CallVoidMethod(myActivity, func, directBuffer, w, h);
```

On `Java` side I received that buffer succesfully, but I cannot use it!

```
public static final void Func(final java.nio.ByteBuffer pixels, int w, int h) {
    boolean ok = pixels.hasArray();
    if (ok)
    {
        java.nio.IntBuffer i_pixels = pixels.asIntBuffer();
        final int[] apixels = i_pixels.array();
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(apixels, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
    // ...
}
```

The first line (`boolean ok = pixels.hasArray();`) just crashes with `UnsupportedOperationException`.

As you can see, I need to convert the buffer received into `int[]` in order to pass it to `Bitmap.createBitmap`. What am I doing wrong and how to achieve what I need?

Comment: Show this bit: `jmethodID func = ...;`

Comment: Also explain "On Java side I received that buffer successfully" how do you know that?

Comment: @weston Debugger shows me correct buffer size for `pixels`. And values for `w` and `h` are also correct. There's nothing wrong with that `func = ...`.

Comment: Even if the direct byte buffer has an array it isn't valid to conclude that the result of `asIntBuffer()` does. NB there isn't such a class as `DirectByteBuffer.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because its a native managed array, you need to access it via the get functions, like getInt()

SEE: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/yNXuiQkGXPY

Comment: Thanks. But it would be a performance hit if I call `getInt` for say million pixels instead of passing them as an array. And `DirectByteBuffer` seems meaningless in my situation. So do you know other way of passing data `C`->`Java` without such an overhead?

Comment: @Nick did you try allocating a native intArray via `NewIntArray` & `SetIntArrayRegion`?  It would double your memory usage of the array, but it would be short lived.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying it right now. It seems that I have sad alternative of either slow processing (using `DirectByteBuffer`) or memory overhead (by `SetIntArrayRegion`)... Anyway I accept your answer and thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `jbyteArray` or `jintarray`? I use that for processing YuV to RGB on native side although I'm passing the `byte[]` from java to `c` should work your way too.